# confirm dialog in dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

How to create a confirm dialog box in dojo? I would like to have an ok cancel dialog to appear on button click with dojo dialog (no javascript confirm dialog).
So far i can only display a dialog on click event.
Heres my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
dojo.require("dijit.Dialog");

var secondDlg;
dojo.ready(function(){
    // create the dialog:
    secondDlg = new dijit.Dialog({
       title: "Programmatic Dialog Creation",
       style: "width: 300px",
   draggable:false
    });
});
showDialogTwo = function(){
   // set the content of the dialog:
   secondDlg.set("content", "Hey, I wasn't there before, I was added at " + new Date() + "!");
   secondDlg.show();
}
</script>
</head>
<body class="claro" style="margin-right:10px;">
<button id="buttonTwo" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" data-dojo-props="onClick:showDialogTwo" type="button">Show me!</button>
</body>
```

How can i make this ok cancel dialog box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution above does not take into account the little cross at the top right of the dialog.

I had done, long ago, a little suite of dialogs, you might find some happiness here, especially ConfirmDialog.js 
I just uploaded them on github today so you can take a look at them : http://github.com/PEM-FR/Dojo-Components/tree/master/dojox/dialog

They should be usable "as-is" or with minor changes

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="dojo/method" event="onClick">
                    var dialog = new dijit.Dialog({
                        title: "Delete Switch Type",
                        style: "width: 400px",
                        content : "Do you really want to delete ?????<br>"
                    });
                   //Creating div element inside dialog
                    var div = dojo.create('div', {}, dialog.containerNode);
                    dojo.style(dojo.byId(div), "float", "left");

                    var noBtn = new dijit.form.Button({
                                label: "Cancel",
                                onClick: function(){
                                    dialog.hide();
                                    dojo.destroy(dialog);
                                }
                             });

                    var yesBtn = new dijit.form.Button({
                                label: "Yes",
                                style : "width : 60px",
                                onClick : <your function here>,
                                dialog.hide();
                    dojo.destroy(dialog);
                                }
                             });
                                  //adding buttons to the div, created inside the dialog
                    dojo.create(yesBtn.domNode,{}, div);
                    dojo.create(noBtn.domNode,{}, div);
                    dialog.show();
                </script>
```

I'm using this code as inline dojo/method - on the click event of the button. you can modify anyway

Answer (score 2):

The Confirm Dialog is supported since Dojo 1.10.

See the [release notes](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/releasenotes/1.10#dialog-tooltip-and-tooltipdialog) and the [documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/ConfirmDialog.html).